# Music Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-Shirt]

**STICKERS!**

[image: Stickers]

**Please Note!** The stickers are actually on a **CLEAR** background. But with the white bars, they won't show up on the white background for this site, so I had to add a background to the example image so you can see what it actually is. You can click on the sticker image to be taken to the image with the clear background.

I'll be reaching out to you later today or tomorrow morning (via e-mail) with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: What would be the Profile Link, if it's not the name I use? The form won't accept that!

Comment: @Tim Copy paste the url out of the address bar for your profile.

Comment: This is awesome! I'll wear this t-shirt with pride, and tell everybody that I'm good at receiving credit for asking questions of which people like to read the answers. :D

Comment: Since not everyone gets it, it seems like we should call it "SMUG" (Stuff Many of Us Get), not "SWAG" (Stuff We All Get).

Comment: Haha, brilliant @ToddWilcox! I must confess this is currently the most exciting thing to happen to me this year (which is very sad, I know). However, it'll drop into second place if Leicester City win the Premier League...

Comment: @BobBroadley - I guess it just dropped to 2nd place :)

Comment: Really looking forward to the stickers - not that this is a subtle hint, but having enough stickers to go on flight cases, instrument cases and a few of my guitars and amps would be very welcome... :-)

Comment: d'oh, I'm on page 5!

Comment: Yay! Schwag! I feel loved...

Comment: Where is the link to the form?

Comment: @luserdroog: You should have got an email with topic "Music Stack Exchange Top User Swag!‏ " where there is a link to the form.

Comment: @awe Thanks. It was in my other email that I don't check much.

Comment: Has the swag  been mailed yet?

Comment: Dang it, I only just found this SE site D:

Answer (score 2):

Got this at my mail today:

[image]

(Greece)

Answer (score 1):

Arrived at the real-world end of the wormhole from the Stack Exchange world! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now I can tell all my friends that I'm one of the 72 most knowledgeable musicians on the Internet... That's right, isn't it? :D

I kid, I kid. Either way, the shirt has arrived and I'm loving it. Thanks a lot for this initiative!